# Help needed to understand proof to Darboux Sum Comparison Lemma

Tags: real-analysis

I have some queries pertaining to the proof of the Darboux sum comparison lemma in the textbook, Advanced Calculus(Patrick Fitzpatrick):

> Suppose $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ and $-M \leq f(x)  \leq M, \forall x \in [a,b].$ Let $P$ be a partition of $[a,b]$ that has $k$ has partition points and $P^{*}$ be any partition of  $[a,b].$
>
> Then, $U(f.P^{*}) \leq U(f,P)+kM\text{gap}P^{*} $ and $L(f,P)-kM\text{gap}P^{*} \leq L(f,P^{*})$

Note that $\text{gap}P^{*} = \text{max}_{i=1,...,n} [x_{i-1},x_i],$ where $P^{*}  =\{x_o,...,x_n\}$ and $U(f,P) \equiv$ upper Darboux sum of $f.$

Here is an excerpt of the proof:
Let $P=\{z_o,...,z_{k-1}\}.$ For $1\leq i \leq n, $ let $M_i = \text{sup} _{x\in [x_{i-1},x_i]}f(x)$ and call the index $i$ a crossing index if $(x_{i-1},x_{i})$ contains a partition point $z_j$ of the partition $P.$ Denote set $C$ the set of crossing indices among the indices $\{1,...,n\}.$

If $i$ is not crossing index, then $(x_{i-1},x_i)$ does not contain partition points of $P$ and therefore the interval $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ of the partition $P^{*}$ is contained in a partition interval of $P.$ Thus, $[x_{i-1},x_i]$is a partition interval of the common refinement $P'$ of $P$ and $P^{*}.$

Therefore, $\sum_{i \not\in C}M_i(x_i-x_{i-1}) \leq U(f,P^{\prime}).$ $< -\bf{May \ I \  know \ why \ this\ is \  true }$?

For eg, if $M_i>0 $ on $[xi−1,xi],i∉C$ and $\text{sup}f<0$ on the rest of the partition intervals of $P′$, then the claim that $\sum_{i \not\in C}M_i(x_i-x_{i-1}) \leq U(f,P^{\prime})$ is false. Please advise, thank you.

Comment: Your doubts are well-founded. See this [errata](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~drogalsk/fitzgerald-errata.pdf) as to p. 184.

Comment: Thanks. May I know what should be the correct statement and proof?

Comment: See this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904970/fitzpatricks-proof-of-darboux-sum-comparison-lemma). I don't understand why it was downvoted: it is right !

Comment: @Tony Piccolo: But the edited statement appears to be equivalent to the original one

Comment: How do you obtain the original statement from the edited one ?

Comment: The original statement is in the form of $A-E \leq B, C \leq D + E.$ The edited one is in the form of $C-B \leq D-A + 2E.$

Comment: So, given the edited statement, we can deduce that $C\leq D + E, B \geq A-E.$

Comment: Oops. I made an error. Given the edited statement, we can also deduce $2E-A \geq C, D \geq -B.$ So both statements are not equivalent.

Comment: Hence, could you advise on the proof to the edited statement?

Comment: It is similar, but from the start consider products of the type $(M_i-m_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})$, non negative in every case.

Answer (score 1):

Here I use a more conservative approach in order to maintain the distinction between upper and lower sums in the original statement.

(I don't use the symbol $E$ to avoid confusion)

If you **only** change $\,-M \le f(x) \le M$ with $\,0 \le f(x) \le M$, the original proof is right!

If you want a result for the case $\,-M \le f(x) \le M$, consider the *auxiliary* function $g(x)=f(x)+M$.

Note that $\,0 \le g(x) \le 2M$, so you can apply the edited theorem to $g\,$.

(**attention**: you use the edited statement directly, you don't have to repeat the proof for $g$ !)

Since **now the upper bound is $2M$**, you obtain $$U(g,P^*) \le U(g,P)+ k \cdot 2M \cdot \text {gap}\, P^*$$ or (translated in $f$) $$U(f,P^*)+ M(b-a) \le U(f,P)+ M(b-a)+ k \cdot 2M \cdot \text {gap}\, P^*$$ i.e. $$U(f,P^*) \le U(f,P)+ k \cdot 2M \cdot \text {gap}\, P^*$$ which is the right inequality in the case $\,-M \le f(x) \le M$.

Finally, if it is supposed $\,m \le f(x) \le M$, then the right inequality is$$U(f,P^*) \le U(f,P)+ k \cdot (M-m) \cdot \text {gap}\, P^*$$ that you obtain using the auxiliary function $g(x)=f(x)-m$.

The same for the lower sums.

Comment: Thanks, if you apply the (edited) theorem to $g,$  you will get $U(g,P^*) \leq U(g,P) + L(g,P^{*}) - L(g,P) +2E \leq U(g,P) + L(g,P^{*}) + 2E .$ How you get $U(g,P) + 2E  \ ?$

Comment: Do you mean the approach in this answer by _the (edited) theorem_ ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: Can you elaborate y

Comment: I mean how do you apply the edited theorem to $g$ to get $U(g,P^*) \leq U(g,P) +2E \ ?$

Comment: Read the edited answer.

Comment: I see that you have used  Fitzpatrick's proof on $g.$ Thank you.

Comment: Read **attention**.

Comment: By the edited statement, we will get $U(g,P^*) \leq U(g,P)+ L(g,P^*)-L(g,P) + 2k\cdot M \cdot \text{gap} \ P^*  \leq U(g,P)+ L(g,P^*) + 2k \cdot M \cdot \text{gap} \ P^*$

Comment: The edited statement says $U(f,P^*) \le U(f,P)+ k \cdot M \cdot \text {gap}\, P^*$ and refers to the case $0\le f(x)\le M$ !

Comment: The edited statement is the one in the answer by user175716 right? See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904970/fitzpatricks-proof-of-darboux-sum-comparison-lemma

Comment: Okay I get you. The original statement is correct for non-negative bounded function. So we apply original statement to $g$ directly since $0\leq g(x) \leq 2M, M>0.$

Comment: May I seek your advice to this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233275/proof-of-newtons-binomial-expansion#_=_

Comment: I agree, there is something unclear. See my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233275/proof-of-newtons-binomial-expansion#_=_).

Answer (score 0):

@Tony Piccolo: Denote $C$ as the set of crossing indices, as defined earlier in Patrick's proof.

It follows that,$\ \sum_{i \in C}M_i(x_i-x_{i-1}) \leq kM\text{gap}P^{*}=E$ and $\sum_{i \in C}m_i(x_i-x_{i-1}) \geq -kM\text{gap}P^{*} \ .$

On other hand, if $i$ is not crossing index, then $[x_{i-1},x_i] \subset [z_{j-1},z_j],$ for some $j.$ $\implies \sum_{i \not\in C}(M_i-m_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})\leq \sum_{j: \ {[x_{i-1},x_i] \subset [z_{j-1},z_j]}}(K_j -k_j)(z_{j}-z_{j-1}) $ $\leq U(f,P) -L(f,P),$  $ \text{where} \ K_j (\text{resp.} \ k_j) \ \text{is sup (resp. inf) of} \ f \ \text{in} \ [z_{j-1},z_j].$

Hence, $U(f,P^*)-L(f,P^*) =  \sum_{i \in C}(M_i-m_i)(x_{i}-x_{i-1})+\sum_{i \not\in C}(M_i-m_i)(x_{i}-x_{i-1})$ $ \leq 2E+ U(f,P)-L(f,P).$

Comment: It is right. Of course more than one $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ can be included in the same $[z_{j-1},z_j]$ but this is not a problem (why ?). However see my answer for another (easier) approach.