# Proof of Newton's Binomial Expansion

Tags: calculus, analysis, proof-explanation

I have some thoughts pertaining to the proof of Newton's Binomial Expansion in Patrick Fritzpatrick's Advanced Calculus.  The theorem is stated as such:

> Let  $\beta$ be any real number, then $$(1+ x)^\beta = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}{{\beta} \choose {k}}x^k, |x| < 1.$$

Here is an excerpt of the proof:

> Consider the case where $-1 < x <0$. Write $(x-t)=-(t-x)$, so $$\ (1+ x)^\beta - \sum^{n}_{k=0}{{\beta} \choose {k}}x^k =(-1)^{n+1}(n+1) {{\beta} \choose {n+1}} \int^{x}_{0} \left(\dfrac{t-x}{1+t}\right)^n(1+t)^{\beta -1}dt. $$
>   Observe that $0\leq \left(\dfrac{t-x}{1+t}\right) \leq -x = |x|, $ if $-1<x \leq t \leq 0,$ so for each natural number $n, \ 0 \leq \left(\dfrac{t-x}{1+t}\right)^n (1+t)^{\beta -1} \leq |x|^n,$ if $-1<x \leq t \leq 0.$

May I know how  one concludes that $ \ 0 \leq \left(\dfrac{t-x}{1+t}\right)^n (1+t)^{\beta -1} \leq |x|^n  \ ?$ What if $\beta -1 < 0 \ ?$

It seems that we do not require $ \ 0 \leq \left(\dfrac{t-x}{1+t}\right)^n (1+t)^{\beta -1} \leq |x|^n  \ $ for the case of  $-1<x \leq 0.$ This is my justification:

> \begin{align}
> &\left|(1+ x)^\beta - \sum^{n}_{k=0}{{\beta} \choose {k}}x^k \right| \\
> =& (n+1)\left|{{\beta} \choose {n+1}} \int^{0}_{x}\left(\dfrac{t-x}{1+t}\right)^n(1+t)^{\beta-1}dt\right| \\
> \leq& (n+1)\left|{{\beta} \choose {n+1}}\right||x|^n \int^{0}_{x} \left|(1+t)^{\beta-1}\right| dt, \ -1<x<0
> \end{align}
>   Since $\lim_{n \to \infty}n{{\beta} \choose {n}}x^n=0, \ (|x|<1, \beta \in \mathbb{R}), \ $  and  $\int^{0}_{x}\left|(1+t)^{\beta-1}\right| dt < \infty,$
>
> it follows that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}(n+1)\left|{{\beta} \choose {n+1}}\right||x|^n\int^{0}_{x}\left|(1+t)^{\beta-1}\right| dt = 0, \ $$ i.e. $$(1+ x)^\beta = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}{{\beta} \choose {k}}x^k, -1<x\leq 0$$

Kindly advise, thank you.

Comment: You may have a look at http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2016/07/the-general-binomial-theorem-part1.html and http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2016/07/the-general-binomial-theorem-part2.html

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

I agree with your doubts: here is the truth.

For all $t$ between $0$ and $x$, one has $$(1+t)^{\beta-1} \le \begin {cases} 1 \qquad\qquad\quad \text{if}\quad \beta\ge1 \,\text{,}\; x\le0 \\ (1+x)^{\beta-1} \quad \text{if}\quad \beta\le1 \,\text{,}\; x\le0 \\ (1+x)^{\beta-1} \quad \text{if}\quad \beta\ge1 \,\text{,}\; x\ge0 \\ 1 \qquad\qquad\quad \text{if}\quad \beta\le1 \,\text{,}\; x\ge0 \end {cases}$$ If you use this bounds, you need not integrate in all the four cases.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have tried to justify that we do not require $ \ 0 \leq \left(\dfrac{t-x}{1+t}\right)^n (1+t)^{\beta -1} \leq |x|^n  \ $ for the case of  $-1<x \leq 0$ and I did not compute any integrals at all. I made use of the fact that $|(1+t)^{\beta-1}|$ is continuous and hence integrable on $t \in [0,x],$ where $-1< x <0. $ Similar reasoning applies to the case of $1> x >0.$